# User being faster than Cloud Function

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function which is creating a user profile in Firestore, right after a user signs up with FirebaseAuth (with E-Mail & Password).

A user document could look like this

```
users/{<uid>}

{
  username:"smith",
  status: "I love pineapple pizza",
  email:"smith@mail.com"
}
```

After signing up, I'm giving my users the chance to change their `status` attribute. The problem is that the user can be faster than the triggered cloud function. This leads to the problem that the user tries to change a document which is ***not*** existing.

How can I make sure that the cloud function is already triggered ?
The only thing which is on my mind is checking from the client side if the document exists (maybe a loop). Which is imo not a really good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking to see if the document already exists is your only approach.  You really don't have any guarantees about how exactly the client and server will interact with each other.  If you need to perform some action on the client, it will have to coordinate with the server, with no assumptions about when exactly a Cloud Function may trigger.

If you want some client code to trigger when a function creates a document in Firestore, just set up a listener on that document (don't use get() - it should be a listener instead).  The listener will get triggered when the document is created, and you will have assurance that the function is complete

Answer (score 3):

You could [attach a listener to the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). With that your `onSnapshot` should fire when the document is created, at which point you can update it.

Depending on the exact writes the client and server need to do, also consider making the writes idempotent. So: ensure that whoever goes first, all writes succeed.